# WebSite Not Running In Azure Locally

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-cloud-services

**EDIT:  Running Visual Studio as an administrator fixes the problem below but can someone explain why I need to run as an administrator in order to run the web site in the Azure emulator?**

We are in the process of migrating our site to Windows Azure, I have created a cloud service and added the website as a web role and when I try to start the cloud service project in debug it won't start and in the output it says:

```
The program '[12396] WaIISHost.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

And in the bottom left corner it says "Operation Cancelled".  I can't seem to find any reason why this is happening, if I create a blank asp.net mvc website it works fine so there must be something in our application that is causing it to bomb like this, does anyone have any idea how to go about tracking this issue down?

I only get a second to look at the emulator output but it says:

```
[fabric] Role Instance: deployment24(29).xxx.Web.0
[fabric] Role state Busy
[fabric] Role state Unhealthy
[fabric] Role state Stopped
```

I found the following entries in waHostBootstrapper.log

```
[00005740:00008088, 2014/09/13, 15:57:43.320, ERROR] <- WapXmlReadRoleModel=0x1
[00005740:00008088, 2014/09/13, 15:57:43.324, ERROR] <- GetDebugger=0x1
[00005740:00008088, 2014/09/13, 15:57:43.324, ERROR] <- GetStartupTaskDebugger=0x1
[00005740:00008088, 2014/09/13, 15:57:43.324, ERROR] <- WapGetEnvironmentVariable=0x800700cb
[00005740:00008088, 2014/09/13, 15:57:43.324, ERROR] <- WapGetEnvironmentVariable=0x800700cb
[00005740:00008088, 2014/09/13, 15:57:43.324, INFO ] Executing Startup Task type=2 rolemodule=Diagnostics cmd="E:\xxx\Diagnostics\DiagnosticsAgent.exe" 
[00005740:00008088, 2014/09/13, 15:57:43.325, INFO ] Executing "E:\xxx\Diagnostics\DiagnosticsAgent.exe" .
[00005740:00008088, 2014/09/13, 15:57:43.334, ERROR] <- WapGetEnvironmentVariable=0x800700cb
[00005740:00008088, 2014/09/13, 15:57:43.335, ERROR] <- WapGetEnvironmentVariable=0x800700cb
[00005740:00008088, 2014/09/13, 15:57:43.335, INFO ] Executing Startup Task type=0 rolemodule=Diagnostics cmd="E:\xxx\Diagnostics\DiagnosticsAgent.exe" /blockStartup
[00005740:00008088, 2014/09/13, 15:57:43.335, INFO ] Executing "E:\xxx\DiagnosticsAgent.exe" /blockStartup.
[00005740:00002464, 2014/09/13, 15:57:43.480, INFO ] Registering client with PID 13152.
[00005740:00002464, 2014/09/13, 15:57:43.480, INFO ] Client DiagnosticsAgent.exe (13152) registered.
[00005740:00002464, 2014/09/13, 15:57:43.493, INFO ] Registering client with PID 11656.
[00005740:00002464, 2014/09/13, 15:57:43.493, INFO ] Client DiagnosticsAgent.exe (11656) registered.
[00005740:00008088, 2014/09/13, 15:57:43.564, INFO ] Program "E:\xxx\Diagnostics\DiagnosticsAgent.exe" /blockStartup exited with 0. Working Directory = E:\xxx\plugins\Diagnostics
[00005740:00008088, 2014/09/13, 15:57:43.564, INFO ] Executing "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Windows Azure Tools\v2.4\Debugger\WindowsAzureDebugger.exe" base\x64\WaIISHost.exe .
[00005740:00008088, 2014/09/13, 15:57:43.565, INFO ] Role host process PID: 5456.
[00005740:00002464, 2014/09/13, 15:57:43.742, INFO ] Registering client with PID 16360.
[00005740:00002464, 2014/09/13, 15:57:43.742, INFO ] Client WaIISHost.exe (16360) registered.
[00005740:00002464, 2014/09/13, 15:57:43.742, INFO ] Client process WaIISHost.exe is the role host.
[00005740:00002464, 2014/09/13, 15:57:43.742, INFO ] Role host process registered.
[00005740:00008572, 2014/09/13, 15:57:43.820, INFO ] Getting status from client DiagnosticsAgent.exe (13152).
[00005740:00008572, 2014/09/13, 15:57:43.820, ERROR] Failed to connect to client DiagnosticsAgent.exe (13152).
[00005740:00008572, 2014/09/13, 15:57:43.820, ERROR] <- CRuntimeClient::OnRoleStatusCallback(0x0000000E8AE90C90) =0x800706ba
[00005740:00008572, 2014/09/13, 15:57:43.820, INFO ] Removing disconnected client: DiagnosticsAgent.exe (13152).
[00005740:00008572, 2014/09/13, 15:57:43.820, INFO ] Getting status from client DiagnosticsAgent.exe (11656).
[00005740:00008572, 2014/09/13, 15:57:43.826, INFO ] Client reported status 0.
[00005740:00008572, 2014/09/13, 15:57:43.826, INFO ] Getting status from client WaIISHost.exe (16360).
[00005740:00008572, 2014/09/13, 15:57:43.826, INFO ] Client reported status 1.
[00005740:00008572, 2014/09/13, 15:57:44.327, INFO ] Getting status from client DiagnosticsAgent.exe (11656).
[00005740:00008572, 2014/09/13, 15:57:44.331, INFO ] Client reported status 0.
[00005740:00008572, 2014/09/13, 15:57:44.331, INFO ] Getting status from client WaIISHost.exe (16360).
[00005740:00008572, 2014/09/13, 15:57:44.331, INFO ] Client reported status 1.
[00005740:00008572, 2014/09/13, 15:57:44.833, INFO ] Getting status from client DiagnosticsAgent.exe (11656).
[00005740:00008572, 2014/09/13, 15:57:44.842, INFO ] Client reported status 0.
[00005740:00008572, 2014/09/13, 15:57:44.842, INFO ] Getting status from client WaIISHost.exe (16360).
[00005740:00008572, 2014/09/13, 15:57:44.842, ERROR] Failed to connect to client WaIISHost.exe (16360).
[00005740:00008572, 2014/09/13, 15:57:44.842, ERROR] <- CRuntimeClient::OnRoleStatusCallback(0x0000000E8AE90CF0) =0x800706ba
[00005740:00008572, 2014/09/13, 15:57:44.842, INFO ] Client process WaIISHost.exe is the role host.
[00005740:00008572, 2014/09/13, 15:57:44.842, WARN ] Failed to contact the role host process. Treat role as unhealthy.
[00005740:00017556, 2014/09/13, 15:57:45.295, INFO ] Sending shutdown notification to client DiagnosticsAgent.exe (11656).
[00005740:00017556, 2014/09/13, 15:57:45.301, INFO ] Sending shutdown notification to client WaIISHost.exe (16360).
[00005740:00017556, 2014/09/13, 15:57:45.302, ERROR] Failed to connect to client WaIISHost.exe (16360).
[00005740:00017556, 2014/09/13, 15:57:45.302, ERROR] <- CRuntimeClient::OnRoleShutdownCallback(0x0000000E8AE90CF0) =0x800706ba
```

Looking in the logs at \AppData\Local\dftmp\Resources{guid}\directory\DiagnosticStore there are errors in the WaIISHost.log which are:

WaIISHost Information: 0 : [00006516:00000001, 2014/09/14 06:43:23.994, ERROR] Exception:System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail]: Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation. (Fault Detail is equal to An ExceptionDetail, likely created by IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true, whose value is:
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.
   at System.Security.AccessControl.Win32.SetSecurityInfo(ResourceType type, String name, SafeHandle handle, SecurityInfos securityInformation, SecurityIdentifier owner, SecurityIdentifier group, GenericAcl sacl, GenericAcl dacl)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The emulator needs admin privileges to perform several of its tasks.  It needs to control IIS, it needs to (often) open ports below 1024, and it needs to have control privileges on the worker processes.  Since Visual Studio is spawning and controlling it, this means Visual Studio needs those privileges as well.

There is now an "Express Emulator" option available which mitigates this, but you are limited to one instance per role, and have to allow IIS to use a random high port.  Instructions for running in Express Emulator mode can be found at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn339018.aspx.

This similar question also has further information: [Windows Azure emulator without admin privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9211588/windows-azure-emulator-without-admin-privileges)

Comment: Links can be helpful as supplemental information, but [link-only answers are strongly discouraged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/228805). Always include a summary of the linked information that's relevant to the question, and explain how it resolves the issue. However, this question appears to be off-topic anyway and should have been asked at [sf].

Comment: I gave a short version of the answer (needs to control IIS), but I can understand your point, edited for more detail. I don't know if I agree that this belongs at Server Fault, as this is a question about development and testing on an emulator, not running a real server.