# Running .NET Core Web API without administrator permissions

Tags: .net, azure, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, windows-server

I developed a .NET Core WebAPI and I'm trying to execute it, but the only way it works is running the WebAPI with administrator rights. I mean, if I log in to the server (a VM on Azure running Windows Server 2016), right click on the exe file and then click on "Run as Administrator", everything works fine. But if I just double click on the exe file (even with my user, which is an administrator user) it seems to run, but it doesn't response any request, even though all related processes (webapi.exe, conhost, etc) are running.
Is there any way to execute the WebAPI without elevated privileges?

Comment: Hope this will help you:[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9211588/windows-azure-emulator-without-admin-privileges)

Comment: Don't put your project under the `C:` drive.

Answer (score 0):

*It looks like you have not configured IIS server correctly. Otherwise, once you go to public IP of the VM, you should be able to see your .NET Core Web API.*

**To install IIS, run below command in VM's PowerShell in Admin mode:**

```
Install-WindowsFeature -name Web-Server -IncludeManagementTools
```

**To install Web management Service, run below command:**

```
Install-WindowsFeature -Name Web-Mgmt-Service
```

**Install Web Deploy on VM** and then, **deploy the Web API through Visual Studio (for instance) on VM Public Static IP.**

For detailed setup and deployment steps, please check out [Deploy Web App In Azure VM Using Visual Studio](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/deploy-web-app-in-azure-vm-using-visual-studio/)